# Rsyslog program name for postfix processes (qmgr, lmtp, cleanup)

Tags: postfix, rsyslog

I would like to filter out the sub-programs of postfix (qmgr, lmtp, and cleanup) on Debian 11, rsyslog 8.2102, and postfix 3.5.13

The logs appear like this:

```
Oct 28 20:06:10 mail postfix/qmgr[915]: BF78660117: removed
```

I have tried the following line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
:programname, contains, "postfix/qmgr" stop
```

But that doesnt work, the logs still get through.
I have also tried this line; also doesn't work:

```
:msg, contains, "qmgr" stop
```

I also figured that using `journalctl -u postfix/qmgr -r` would maybe give me more information. But that doesn't return any logs, despite there being postifx qmgr logs in the journal.
Also `journalctl -u postfix -r` doesn't return any logs either.

What is the actual program name for postfix's qmgr, lmtp, and cleanup? I can't seem to find much about this online, definitely missing something here.
Is there a way for rsyslog to filter on the program name of postfix's processes?

Comment: Seems correct to me, but I think when using the *old* syntax you need to use `& stop` instead of `stop`.

Comment: `stop` seems to work all my other `:msg` filters. What should the entire line look like?

Comment: I just checked the documentation, seems like I was wrong. If you haven't changed too much in your config, this should disable all postfix logging `*.*;mail.none;mail.error;auth,authpriv.none             -/var/log/syslog`. Note the **.none**.

Comment: That certainly can help. But I dont want to disable all postfix logging, just the logging for particular processes of postfix. qmgr and cleanup I don't much care for the logs.